# Bracha on smelling thyme?

Tags: halacha, blessing, smell

I'd like to know what bracha to say on smelling [thyme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thyme).

Does it have סימני אילן as described in the helachos of borei pri haeitz? Biur Halacha on 216:3, "עצי בשמים", concludes that it needs to have the same criteria in order for it not to be a safeik.

From Googling "thyme", it's an evergreen, so it doesn't die out and regrow. As far as I can tell it grows a stem, and when the stem finishes growing, then the stem grows leaves - but I'm not sure about this. Biur halacha ibid. sends you to Rema on 203:2, where Rema explains why strawberries are not eitz.

I'm *pretty sure* it's eitz, but I would like confirmation.

Comment: Check vzot habracha which probably talks about this

Comment: I don't have a copy of that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[This list](http://halachayomit.com/kolsasson/006%20KS%20Vayechi.pdf), compiled by R' Shimon Buchnik (a Sephardi rav in Chashmonaim) says one should recite "עצי בשמים" on thyme (בת קורנית), as you suggest.

However, [this source](http://shut.moreshet.co.il/print.asp?id=45743&kod=&modul=15&codeClient=56) (from [R' David Lau](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Lau)) says that the custom is to recite "עשבי בשמים" on thyme<sup>1</sup> even though he says that one would think you should recite "מיני בשמים".

[*Reiach HaSadeh*](http://www.nehora.com/reiach-hasadeh-the-fragrant-field/) (by R' Hanoch Slatin, p. 142) indicates that one should recite "מיני בשמים". The reason given is that, since thyme is primarily used as a seasoning in foods, there is a possibility that one should recite "הנותן ריח טוב בפירות", which is the appropriate blessing for enjoying the fragrance of edible fruit.<sup>2</sup> Due to uncertainty on this point, R' Slatin indicates that the generic form is preferred (based on a similar ruling from *Mishna B'rura* 216:16 and *Sha'ar HaTziyun* 216:12 regarding cloves and cinnamon).

---

<sup>1</sup>  <sub>I'm not certain why the custom would be to recite "*borei isvei*". Perhaps there is some botanical difference between the common thyme ([Thymus vulgaris](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thymus_vulgaris)) and [Thymus capitatus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thymus_capitatus) or [Thymus bovei](http://eol.org/pages/5371803/details) that commonly grow in Israel, and perhaps the "טימין" referred to by R' Lau is derived from one of the latter varieties.</sub>

<sup>2</sup> <sub>There is some difference of opinion regarding the *nusach* of this blessing, and the *Mishna B'rura* (216:9) prefers "אשר נתן ריח טוב בפירות " (similar to the formulation of "שנתן" found in the *Shulchan Aruch*), referring to the creation of the fragrant quality of fruits in the past tense.</sub>